# ¿Cómo descifrar texto en C, usando la ecuacion: p = ax + b (mod 26)?

Tags: c, cifrado

tengo que hacer un ****procedimiento en C** que descifre texto**, leyendo dos strings y utilizando la ecuación:

***p = [ax + b](mod 26)***

*Donde x es la posición de la letra en ASCII, y p es el valor en ASCI por el cual quiero cambiar la letra original*

***La cosa es que no sé por dónde empezar***, la idea es que me den un texto cifrado, y una palabra (la cual esta dentro del texto) con la cual pueda hallar los valores de a y b para poder descifrar todo el texto.

Por ejemplo, la primera cadena es "OXOGLQJIMOGXUEXUVORUBUURBMZUBOGLUUGIYHULQBU"

Y la segunda cadena es la palabra "ESTUDIO"

En este caso la clave privada es (a, b) = (5, 7) y el mensaje es: ELESTUDIOESLACLAVEPARAAPROBARESTAASIGNATURA.

Estuve leyendo de varios tipos de cifrado, y la verdad no sé cómo empezar el programa.
Lo único que se me ocurre es hacerlo con todas las combinaciones posibles de a,b dentro de {0,...25} con varios for, pero me quedaría muy muy largo y de seguro hay alguna forma más eficiente.

**Se agradece cualquier tipo de ayuda!**

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio. ¡Intenta algo! Cuando no puedes con algo debido a su complejidad, siempre es bueno ver cómo harías con un caso más simple o dividir el problema en partes. Por ejemplo, `x + b`. Luego sube el código que hayas hecho.

Comment: Si tienes dudas acerca de la expresión `(ax + b) mod 26` pregunta por ello. Pero tu pregunta terminará cerrada si simplemente dices: "No sé que hacer". O "He intentado varias cosas pero ninguna sirve" si no nos muestras el código.